# Object graphs in swagger clients

Tags: openapi, swagger-codegen

**Situation**

I am working on an OpenAPI v3 specification for an existing codebase. The approach is based on swagger-core in a jaxrs (jersey) context. The API will need to support a graph consisting of vertices (entities with properties) and edges (linking vertices, possibly having properties). For json (de)serialisation, we're relying on jackson.

The model (related to graphs) is something like:

```yaml
Vertex:
  type: object
  ...
  properties:
    id:
      type: string
    ...

Edge:
  type: object
  ...
  properties:
    start:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Vertex'
    destination:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Vertex'
```

**Issues / challenges**

There are two issues:

- *Overhead*: This schema (and how we're using it) would result in vertices to be repeated in the start and destination fields of edges. This is unnecessary payload which may be considerable for large vertices (may properties / large values) and many edges referencing these vertices.
- *Correctness*: A more serious issue is that it may be unclear which vertex is the correct vertex. I.e. multiple instances of Vertex may occur in a request / response with the same id, but with different values. This seems error prone.

**Directions of solution**

In the API side, we can use @JsonIdentityInfo and @JsonIdentityReference to resolve these issues. However, it seems impossible to generate clients that work with this.

I guess the main issue here is the lack of support from the OpenAPI specification / JSON schema to support object references.

In my "google endeavours" the waters are muddied a lot by content around references in OAS / JSON schema themselves ... go figure.

I've been looking into [JSON Reference](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03) and [Javascript Object Graph](https://github.com/jsog/jsog), but I have found no hooks to incorporate these ideas into an OAS schema.

*Model reference as string*

The most likely route to take for me is to model the start and destination properties of `Edge` as `string`s. That at least solves the issues above. This does bring up a new issue: clients generated by swagger are less intuitive to use:

```java
new Edge()
   .start(vertexA.getId())
   .destination(vertexB.getId())
```

instead of

```java
new Edge()
   .start(vertexA)
   .destination(vertexB)
```

The issue is worse even when reading responses:

```java
Vertex start = graph.getVertices().stream()
     .filter(v -> v.getId().equals(edge.getStart()))
     .findFirst();
Vertex destination = graph.getVertices().stream()
     .filter(v -> v.getId().equals(edge.getDestination()))
     .findFirst();
```

instead of

```java
Vertex start = edge.getStart();
Vertex destination = edge.getDestination();
```

To make matters even worse still is that the API will have a class hierarchy for both `Vertex` and `Edge`. When using `string` as type for the start and destination properties, the type safety in the client is down the drain.

**Help**

Does anyone have experience with this type of schema? Any advice on how to model the schema and/or support in client generators?

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing exactly the same, especially regarding the google search: there are lot of JSON schema reference hits, none of them relevant to complex object graph serialization.

What I did on the server side (java): I have my own object serializer, which smart enough, to handle object references. Every object has an id. When the object first serialized, the serializer's output is the object JSON representation. When an object reoccur in the graph, the serializer only outputs the object reference with #objectid.

For example:

```
    {
    "created": "05/03/2020 17:49:08",
    "name": "Object Group [5109]",
    "objectID": 5109,
    "elements": [
        {
            "created": "05/03/2020 17:49:08",
            "name": "Element [5110]",
            "description": "Object example [5109]",
            "objectID": 5110
            "parent": #5109
        },
       ...
    ]
}
```

Of course if you want to represent the object graph properly on the client side, this has to be deserialized in JavaScript code, and set the client side object references during deserialization. I don't know any mechanism for this in openapi generated clients.

Comment: Doesn't that forego the point of using OpenAPI Schema? Or whatever schema? In our setup we use Jackson which has fine support for what you describe; see https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html and friends.

My question is more along the lines of: how can we express this in an OAS API such that clients generated from it "just work"; i.e. have object deduplication in requests / responses while still having full object graphs in the model code generated.